# NoClassDefFoundError when using avro in spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-avro

I keep getting

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/mapred/AvroWrapper

when calling `show()` on a DataFrame object. I'm attempting to do this through the shell (spark-shell --master yarn). I can see that the shell recognizes the schema when creating the DataFrame object, but if I execute any actions on the data it will always throw the `NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to instantiate the `AvroWrapper`. I've tried adding `avro-mapred-1.8.0.jar` in my `$HDFS_USER/lib` directory on the cluster and even included it using the --jar option when launching the shell. Neither of these options worked. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Below is example code:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql._
scala> import com.databricks.spark.avro._
scala> val sqc = new SQLContext(sc)
scala> val df = sqc.read.avro("my_avro_file") // recognizes the schema and creates the DataFrame object
scala> df.show // this is where I get NoClassDefFoundError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this problem, I finally solved it. I removed the CDH spark package and downloaded it from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html. After that everything worked fine. Not sure what the issues was with the CDH version, but I'm not going to waste anymore time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

The DataFrame object itself is created at the `val df =...` line, but data is not read yet. Spark only starts reading and processing the data, when you ask for some kind of output (like a `df.count()`, or `df.show()`).

So the original issue is that the avro-mapred package is missing.
Try launching your Spark Shell like this:

`spark-shell --packages org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1`

The Spark Avro package marks the Avro Mapred package as provided, but it is not available on your system (or classpath) for one or other reason.

Comment: it appears to just sit there. won't progress beyond.

`org.apache.avro#avro-mapred added as a dependency`
`com.databricks#spark-avro_2.10 added as a dependency`
`:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0`
 `confs: [default]`

Comment: That's weird. Can you paste the entire command you are using to launch spark-shell?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response I had to switch tasks for a couple days. Here's the command I'm running `spark-shell --master yarn --packages org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1`. Also, not sure if it makes a difference, but we are running CDH 5.6. Thanks again.

Comment: This might seem weird, but try with the `--packages` as the first argument and `--master` as the second. Also did you give it a try using the local master?

Comment: After waiting a considerable amount of time I finally got an error: `Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro-mapred/1.7.7/avro-mapred-1.7.7.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out)`. I'm sure it has everything to do with our proxy.

Comment: Some progress. Using `spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=9000 -Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=9000" --packages org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1 --master yarn` I'm able to get the dependencies, but now it's failing on `[download failed: org.mortbay.jetty#jetty;6.1.26!jetty.zip]`

Comment: I've resolved all the dependency issues, but I still get the same `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/mapred/AvroWrapper`. If I run locally it works fine, but that sort of defeats the purpose as it's a large amount of data I'm trying to analyze. At this point I'm switching tactics and am going to deploy instead of using the shell. Thanks for your help.